# Atom Editor Setting Preferred Line Length For Markdown Files

Tags: markdown, line, config, atom-editor

I am trying to create a preferred line length soft wrap for my Markdown files in Atom Editor. I am aware I can universally change the preferred line length, but I want to change the Preferred Line Length for just Markdown files.
I have a (built-in?) package by Atom called "language-text" that allows me to change the Line Length of .txt files and the config.cson code looks like this:

```
".plain.text":
  editor:
    preferredLineLength: 60
    softWrapAtPreferredLineLength: true
```

In theory, I could add this to my config.cson file and it would do the same for Markup files, correct?

```
".text.md": 
  editor:
    preferredLineLength: 60
    softWrapAtPreferredLineLength: true
```

However it is not working. Am I making any mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

### Manual Editing

You were on the right track but probably used an incorrect syntax scope for Markdown. There are several ”flavors” of Markdown, so you first need to identify what you're using – by default, Atom uses “GitHub Markdown” (`.source.gfm)`.

To identify the scope in use, open a Markdown file and run the *Editor: Log Cursor Scope*. For the default, it will print something like this:

[image]

### Settings UI

Alternatively, you can achieve the same by opening the Atom *Settings*, selecting the *Packages* pane, and clicking on your preferred Markdown package. You can now change the value for selected language grammar in the UI.

[image]